# mimeMap not working in Azure Website

Tags: c#, azure, iis, owin, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure website that consists of several virtual applications. The root application has URL rewrite rules for a SPA (angular):

```
<rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*"/>
  <conditions  logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <!--Is not file-->
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
    <!--Is not directory-->
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
    <!--Is not /api-->
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true"/>
    <!--Is not *.extension-->
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.(ashx|axd|css|gif|png|mov|MOV|avi|ttf|jpg|jpeg|js|flv|f4v|woff|woff2|json)$" negate="true"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/"/>
</rule>
```

The root application also has a very small OWIN/Katana middleware application that runs the static files middleware to return a single page based on a condition. RAMMFAR is turned off and thus the static files middleware is only used to return the homepage.

My problem is that I have .woff, .woff2, and .json files that refuse to load in Azure, but load fine in local IIS. I have a web.config that has the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff"/>

    <remove fileExtension=".woff2"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2"/>

    <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

This does NOT work in Azure. It works well locally, but not in Azure. I've even put web.configs in each folder that the files reside in to make sure the rules are not overwritten. I think it may be related to using virtual applications within an Azure Website, but I cannot change my site structure. How can I make these .woff, .woff2, and static json files be served properly?
**edit: just checked IIS logs and have found failed request tracing for one of the files. I'm getting a "SECURITY_DENIED_BY_MIMEMAP" error, which means it is something to do with the web.config not getting picked up by IIS.**

**TLDR: even though I have the appropriate web.config (as far as I know), woff, json, and woff2 files are returning 404 even though they exist on the server in the specified location.**

Comment: Have you checked whether the .woff issue happens with a plain Azure Web App (no virtual dirs)? If it does, it would help reduce the complexity that comes with the question, down to something much simpler to describe.

Comment: I was not able to repro this with either a plain app or using a virtual app, so I'm guessing there are other factors. If you you can share your site name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly), that could help investigate.

Comment: From the spec, http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b, you should use `application/font-woff`.  we use that successfully on all Azure WebApps.

Comment: @viperguynaz I will switch to that but I've tried both and neither works. david the other factor is what I am doing in the middleware. I will post that code.

Comment: @DavidEbbo I've posted the code of my middleware. I haven't checked without the virtual directories--my app is such that it needs to call an api on another application in the same azure website in order to run. I might try disabling all of the checks and trying that.

Comment: just checked iis logs for a failed request and getting "SECURITY_DENIED_BY_MIMEMAP"

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but it is a web site project and not an 'asp.net web application' in Visual Studio

Comment: Just checked and the deployment slot works fine, but for some reason the production slot doesn't work right.

Comment: Swapping slots made it work. Very strange.

Answer (score 2):

There is only a single way to do this currently, and I confirmed this with the Azure team.

Add a web.config file to the root of the application `wwwroot\web.config` with the following contents

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="application/mp4" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OWIN/Katana, you'll need to handle static files - add Nuget Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles `Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles`.

Comment: Already using static files middleware and it is quite happily serving up every other file